# How do I recover access to my account?

Tags: google-account, account-recovery

I have a Google account with its recovery address set to a Yahoo address.

Both of my Google and Yahoo accounts were hacked, and I can't login because the passwords no longer work.

I have tried repeatedly to regain access to my Google account but, each time, I am instructed to check my Yahoo address, which I'm locked out of.

How can I recover access to my Google account without the password, and without access to the recovery address?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se].  Yahoo and Google are completely different companies with  different web apps and different account recovery processes. The way your question was written, it appeared to be two different questions combined together.  I have edited it to focus on a single web app.  As a new site user, please visit [ask] and take the [Tour].  You can post a sepperate new question about Yahoo account recovery and have the questions reference (link to) each other if desirable.